# const path = require('path') -- Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, antlr4, node-modules

I followed [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/compiler-in-javascript-using-antlr-9ec53fd2780f) tutorial which describes how to create a JavaScript Compiler for an ANTLR4 grammar (ECMAScript.g4). As an example, it also describes how to transform something from JavaScript to Python. [This is the link](https://github.com/SharkJ/My-JScript-Compiler-for-ANTLR4.git) to the repo of my project.

However, when I run the program through the command prompt, I get the below error:

```
D:\js-runtime>npm start

> js-runtime@1.0.0 start D:\js-runtime
> node index.js

D:\js-runtime\codegeneration\PythonGenerator.js:123
const path = require('path');
      ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\js-runtime\index.js:4:25)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! js-runtime@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the js-runtime@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shjslk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-31T08_28_59_802Z-debug.log
```

Here are the relevant parts of PythonGenerator.js:

```
const ECMAScriptVisitor = require('../lib/ECMAScriptVisitor').ECMAScriptVisitor;

/**
 * This Visitor walks the tree generated by parsers and produces Python code
 *
 * @returns {object}
 */
class Visitor extends ECMAScriptVisitor {

  // lots of method definitions here

  const path = require('path');
  const {
    SemanticArgumentCountMismatchError
  } = require(path.resolve('error', 'helper'));

  // more methods
}
module.exports = Visitor;
```

Clearly, the error must have something to do with the 'path' Node module. But I cannot see what is wrong with it. What might be the cause for this?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself, not as a link (especially not one to an entire project or one that can (and did) change).

Comment: Do note that this almost certainly has nothing to do with the path module. It's a syntax error. It occurred because `const foo = bar;` isn't allowed to appear wherever you wrote it. It never even got to the point of executing the `require`, so the module you're requiring has nothing to do with it. I'm sure if you replace that line with `const x = 42;`, you'd get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**I resolved this by commenting the statements declaring and using the path Node module in the PythonGenerator.js file.**

However, I do not know why this happened. If anyone knows the valid reason, please add it as an answer, and I will accept it as the answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

You can't put constant or variable definitions inside the body of a class definition in JavaScript. You should define `path` and `SemanticArgumentCountMismatchError` outside of the definition of the `Visitor` class.